# Does anyone know the link for the latest version of developer guide for Lightning Web Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, developer-productivity

I am trying to find a pdf copy of Developer guide for Lightning Web Components. I am only able to find online web version. Is the pdf version not published any more?

Answer (score 1):

As per 
[Documentation](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/238/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/lwc.pdf), Developer guide for lightning web components is located [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc), and we do not have any direct pdf version.